# how to reduce the background-color width of text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

How can I reduce the width of the background color so that instead of extending the width of the entire column on bootstrap, its approximately only the length of the text?

For reference I have the background properties like color and border radius within the same `<p>` tag as the text

Thats what I have right now

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding the background color, to the column, add the background color to the text itself, then you can add padding to space.

ex:

```
<div class="col">
<p class="text-primary">.text-primary</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thats what I did tho, the color in the column is light-gray, the color in the tag is blue. That is the output when I do style background-color inside the p tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an element such as `<span>` that has a predefined `display: inline` or add `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to your existing element, e.g.:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col">
  <p class="bg-primary text-white" style="display: inline-block">January 2020 - March 2020</p>
</div>
```

or

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col">
  <span class="bg-primary text-white">January 2020 - March 2020</span>
</div>
```

Both resulting in the same result:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing things is to add a span and add your background-color to the span class.

```
<p class="myTag">
    <span class="highlight">hello</span>
</p>
```

And your css would be

```
.highlight{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Or you could just simply change the display style of your p-tag class like so:

```
<p class="myTag">hello</p>
```

And your css would be

```
.myTag{
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```